# Are there any branches of mathematics where causality is incorporated?

Tags: causality

Are there any branches of mathematics where causality is incorporated? For example, in Bayesian probability:

$$ \ P(B|A) =  \dfrac{P(A ∩ B)}{P(A)} \ $$

likewise:

$$ \ P(B|A) =  \dfrac{P(A | B)P(B)}{P(A)} \ $$

there doesn't seem to be a notion of time or causality since `A` could happen before `B` or vice versa.

Is there a way to determine that `B` is a necessary but not sufficient event for `A` to happen, for example? For example, the probability that B happens given A is zero B happens before A, but some other value if A happens first?

Comment: Check out Judea Pearl's notion of a causal network: https://www.google.com/search?q=pearl+causal+networks

Comment: See my answer on CrossValidated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/568281/is-there-any-theory-or-field-of-study-that-concerns-itself-with-modeling-causati/568294#568294.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is, in fact it is called "Causality"

There absolutely is a branch of Math/Stats/CS dealing with precisely such a statistical notion of causality. Most people in the field would simply refer to it as "Causality". The [Book of Why](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/WHY/) gives a good introduction to the main ideas, and the [Elements of Causal Inference](https://library.oapen.org/bitstream/id/056a11be-ce3a-44b9-8987-a6c68fce8d9b/11283.pdf) presents the foundations and a broader view of the field. For a more comprehensive treatment of structural causal models, have a look at the book [Causality](http://bayes.cs.ucla.edu/BOOK-2K/).

Literature in the field can be found in dedicated venues such as the  [Journal of Causal Inference](https://www.degruyter.com/journal/key/jci/html?lang=en) or the Conference on [Causal Learning and Reasoning](https://www.cclear.cc/2023), but is perhaps most often published in broader venues in Statistics and, more recently but very notably, machine learning.